# A better music control on lock screen

Tags: lock-screens, music-player

I am new to the android world, used to be an iphone user.
I would like to know how can I get a better music control player on my lock screen?
Is there anyway to add more options, like the trackbar to move forward within the song, repeat and random buttons etc?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Rocket Music Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrtstudio.AnotherMusicPlayer&hl=en). It has all the features and option you asked in your question like `Prev`, `Next`, `Random`, `Forward-Rewind`(Track bar control), `Repeat`.

**Additional Options:**

You can even access the player's `Playlist`, `Go to Album`, `Go to Artist`, `Add to Playlist`, `Delete`, `Ringtone` from the lock screen itself by clicking the three dots at the bottom right of the display.

For this to appear in your lock screen you need to, Install Rocket Player and open the music player's and go-to

`Settings > Operation > Lock Options > Rocket Player`.

Take a look at the screenshots for enabling this,

[image: Screenshot_Home] [image: Screenshot_Operations]

[image: Screenshot_LockOptions] [image: Screenshot_Settings_Player]  [image: Screenshot_Lock_screen]

<sub>Screenshots (Click to enlarge images)</sub>

To unlock the screen you need to just swipe the Blue Arrow to the right side blue dot.

Hope its useful. Enjoy Music!!!

Comment: Hi, is this possible to do with Samsung Grand Prime? I can't seem to find the Operation in the settings menu, nor the Lock Options anyware :(

Comment: @Jonathan What is the OS version of your Samsung Grand Prime? I'm sure it will be there under your Music Player's settings. (Don't confuse with the device settngs menu). Check the screenshots in my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, I confused it with the settings menu. Do you know if rocket player work with google music? I will give it a try. Thank you